# programming Language to acess data on Team foundation server

Tags: web-applications

I need to know which programming language would be preferable to create a web application to work with data stored on TFS? And A dropdownlist must be created to access the area path in TFS showing directories, sub directories, so we can select an option to navigate based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

As of TFS 2015 programmatic access is done via a REST API, which pretty much any modern language can consume.

Prior to TFS 2015 there was a SOAP API and a .Net client library.

Comment: How about using web forms in Visual studio? @Dylan Smith

Comment: If you mean ASP.Net web forms then you can call the REST API from C# in your ASP.Net project (or use the client libs for older TFS)